# tSQL to count occurrences in group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For a table with 2 columns:

```
groupA  jobA-1
groupA  jobA-2
groupA  jobA-3
groupB  jobB-1
groupB  jobB-1
groupB  jobB-1
```

I need to query it and get the count of occurrences of each job within the group.

The result I'm looking for is:

```
groupA  jobA-1  1
groupA  jobA-2  1
groupA  jobA-3  1
groupB  jobB-1  3
groupB  jobB-1  3
groupB  jobB-1  3
```

I am just OK with tSQL and can't figure out how to do this.

EDIT: Added a column (Node number)
May I expand this question to ask if there is a way to flag the first occurrence of a job within a group?  So the result would be:

```
Group    Job    NodeNumber Occurrences  FirstOccurance
groupA  jobA-1  2          1            1
groupA  jobA-2  3          1            1
groupA  jobA-3  4          1            1
groupB  jobB-1  7          3            1
groupB  jobB-1  8          3            NULL
groupB  jobB-1  9          3            NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `count()` aggregate window function with [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
select grp, job, count(*) over (partition by grp, job) as cnt
from t
```

---

For the updated question:

```
select 
    grp
  , job
  , NodeNumber
  , count(*) over (partition by grp, job) as Occurrences
  , case when row_number() over (partition by grp, job order by (select 1)) = 1 
      then 1 
      else null 
      end as FirstOccurance
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SNUVMD94771

returns:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+----------------+
|  grp   |  job   | Occurrences | FirstOccurance |
+--------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| groupA | jobA-1 |           1 | 1              |
| groupA | jobA-2 |           1 | 1              |
| groupA | jobA-3 |           1 | 1              |
| groupB | jobB-1 |           3 | 1              |
| groupB | jobB-1 |           3 | NULL           |
| groupB | jobB-1 |           3 | NULL           |
+--------+--------+-------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a windowed `COUNT(*)`:

```
Select  Col1, Col2, 
        Count(*) Over (Partition By Col1, Col2) As Col3
From    YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated.

Comment: (can't figure out how to edit/format a followup question).  May I expand this question to ask if there is a way to flag the first occurrence of a job within a group?  So the result would be:   groupA  jobA-1  1  1
groupA  jobA-2  1  1
groupA  jobA-3  1  1
groupB  jobB-1  3  1
groupB  jobB-1  3
groupB  jobB-1  3

Comment: @shorton SQL data represents *unordered sets*, and based on the table definition defined in the question, you don't have any concept of *when* or in *what order* the records were entered.  So, with that said, with your current structure, getting the first occurrence in a group is impossible.  You will need to add something to indicate the order (e.g. an `ID` column or a `DateEntered`, etc.)